# Eclipse autocomplete with "("

Tags: java, eclipse, autocomplete

I want to disable the Eclipse autocomplete when pressing <kbd>(</kbd>. What I mean - I want to make method with name `some`, so I start typing `private static some` and after that I want to put <kbd>(</kbd>, but Eclipse autocompletes me `SOAPMessage` (when I typing `some`), so after pressing <kbd>(</kbd> I have `SOAPMessage`, not `some(`.

I was stopped this with " " (space) with some plugin, so when I press <kbd>space</kbd>, there is no problem (it doesn't autocomplete). Also I set autocomplete to be triggered when typing (so I don't use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>space</kbd> every time). But this problem with <kbd>(</kbd> is really anoying, because I should add space (so autocomplete disappear, after then backspace and after that to add <kbd>(</kbd>).

I hope, I explaing my problem in details.

Answer (score 0):

- There must come a type name after `private static` so `private static some()` is illegal.
- What is in your [Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Content Assist -> Auto Activation -> Auto activation triggers for Java]? The default setting (I think) is "." alone.

Comment: This is there: ._abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ

Comment: @DPM You changed it that way, right? So Eclipse is told to bring up the content-assist window on every letter you type, and you are supposed to type a type name after `private static` keywords, so auto-completing `SOAPMessage` is indeed the most clever behavior! :) If you typed `private static String` then `some` (the correct Java code), it does not popup.

Comment: Thanks, for your attention. Yes, I did it in that way, because it is more convinient for me, but why when I click space it autocompletes the word ? I want to autocomplete it only with "Enter".